# Lucene query fuzzyquery

Tags: java, lucene

I want to apologize first for my poor English I'm new to loosen and I didn't really understand the query documentation, I indexed some docs and made this query code but its not working

```
Term t = new Term("description", "history"); 
        Query q = new FuzzyQuery(t, 2); 
        int hitsPerPage = 100; 

        Path indexPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Win 7\\Desktop\\projet_ri\\index");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath);
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher iSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopDocs topdocs = iSearcher.search(q, hitsPerPage);
        ScoreDoc[] resultsList = topdocs.scoreDocs; 
        System.out.println("Tab size: "+resultsList.length); // This prints Tab size: 0
        for(int i = 0; i<resultsList.length; i++){ 
            Document book = iSearcher.doc(resultsList[i].doc); 
            String description = book.getField("description").stringValue();
            System.out.println(description);
            }
```

The program isnt even entering the loop, i tried to check resultsList tab and it prints that the size is zero
Can someone help me to correct my code or give me a query example code ?

Comment: Your query looks fine. What terms in your index are you expecting the query to match? How is the "description" field analyzed?

Comment: Im expeting the query to match the term history, i used the method Term(String fld, String text) from Lucene Documentation, and i didnt understood your second question sir

Comment: Presumably you have indexed some documents with a field called "description". So what analyzer did you use for that field? Basically, I suspect there is some disconnect between how you are indexing content, and how you are searching for it.

Comment: thats a fair point, you should use the same analyzer for searching as you use for indexing. apache lucene rule nr.1 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually missed using a QueryParser for your query.
This QueryParser needs the same Analyzer as you use for indexing. This is really important, otherwise the resultset may differs from what you expect. Your sequence should be something like this:

1. open Index
2. create IndexSearcher
3. create QueryParser with on indexing used Analyzer
4. create Query with given search terms
5. parse Query with QueryParser
6. search
7. close everything!

See basic lucene tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_search_operation.htm

Comment: Thank you ! This is what was missing

Comment: I cant find QueryParser in my Libraries, QueryParser queryParser; throws and error, and i cant import the queryparser i cant find it

Comment: StandardQueryParser probably you have to look at lucene javadoc:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html

Comment: Im using Lucene 5.3.1, and when i declare the QueryParser it shows that its an unknown type

Comment: Maybe i should upgrade to lucene 7, because on 5.3.1 i dont think that there's query parser

Comment: i think there should be but yes upgrade to 7.x.x if possible